# Proper Use of __builtin_expect

Tags: c++

I have what should be a canonical case for `__builtin_expect` but I can't seem to get it working and I'm looking for any and all advice on how to best take advantage of the technique.

I have a function of the form

```
void function() {

  // Do some stuff

  if (__builtin_expect((cond1),0)) {
     // Do something expensive
  }

  if (__builtin_expect((cond2),0)) {
    // Do something expensive
  }

  if (__builtin_expect((cond3),0)) {
    // Do something expensive
  }

}
```

where `// Do something expensive` refers to memory allocation, copying, and deallocation for the expansion of stacks.  Now `cond1`, `cond2`, and `cond3` will be true VERY rarely, ideally only on the first call of the function, and my hope was that the `__builtin_expect` would ensure that the branches are optimized appropriately.

Unfortunately having nontrivial code in the if statements drastically slows down my code, even with the `__builtin_expect` and even if the conditions are never true during execution.  Am I using the `__builtin_expect` incorrectly?  Is there little room for optimization because the statements are at the end of a function?  I've tried wrapping the `// Do something expensive` code in separate functions and various permutations thereof with little success as well.

In case it's relevant I'm on an i7 and using clang 3.4.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: From what you're saying, your function() executes slowly even when none of the conditions evaluate to true ? How slow is slow, does it make a difference when you replace the body of the `if` statements with simple printf()s (which also will verify that you never hit that code) ? And are the evaluation of the conditions themselves expensive ?

Comment: Right -- when the bodies of the if statements are nontrivial (for example, adding iostream calls) the code slows down drastically, on the order of 20-40% depending on how you count, even when the statements never evaluate to true.  If the bodies are simple arithmetic statements then the slow down disappears, presumably because the compiler can work its magic.  The conditions themselves are just comparisons (is stack pointer greater than stack size?).

Comment: After spending the weekend learning and subsequently running through the generated assembly it looks like __builtin_expect is indeed working as expected (the jump tables are rearranged as desired).  It looks like what's happening is that the function was being heavily optimized and the presence of the branch was enough to bump the code size up above the inline threshold and causing the increased overhead.  Thanks to anyone who took a look.